# Limit of series in probability using central limit theorem

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Using central limit theorem , evaluate

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n}{j+n-1 \choose j}(\frac{1}{2^{n+j}})$,

I multiplied and divided the series by $1/2$ , And made it look like a binomial distribution ,but they are not i.i.d., which is why I cannot apply CLT.

Comment: I think you are confusing distributions and  random variables

Comment: Then how shall i proceed?

Comment: For a given $n$, interpret the sum as the probability of an event related to a series of coin-flipping experiments.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution for some suggestive formulas. The limit will then be the chance of a particular event associated with a standard Normal variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Some elaborations on whuber's hint:*

Suppose you flip a fair coin repeatedly. What is the probability that your $n$th heads appears on the $(n+j)$th flip? Knowing this, can you write your sum as the probability of some event?

> Your sum is the probability of getting [at least] $n$ heads in $2n$ flips.

Then, use what you know the Central Limit Theorem says about the distribution of heads in a number of coin flips (binomial distribution), as the number of coin flips tends to infinity.